# VBA Copy Sheet.PROTECTED to new workbook ISSUE

Tags: vba, excel

I have a problem with copying of the worksheet from "workbook.protected" to new one. The macro proceeds as follows: firstly Unprotect required sheets, than creates a new workbook, copy sheets to new workbook, re-save all cells in the new workbook as .values, save & close workbook, and finally protect the parent workbook. 
The problem is that due to some reasons the new workbook contains not a values but references to a parent workbook. Could you please advice on that issue?
The code I am using is as follows:

```
Global path As String
Global filename As String

Sub SaveSheet()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim sh1 As Worksheet
Dim sh2 As Worksheet
On Error Resume Next
Set sh1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1")
Set sh2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet2")
sh1.Unprotect Password:="password"
sh2.Unprotect Password:="password"
Dim a As String

 path = "\\path\"
 filename = "file1234"

Set wb = Workbooks.Add

ThisWorkbook.Activate
Sheets("sheet1").Copy Before:=wb.Sheets(1)
ThisWorkbook.Activate
Sheets("sheet2").Copy Before:=wb.Sheets(1)


With wb
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
wb.Activate
Sheets(5).Delete
Sheets(4).Delete
Sheets(3).Delete
Sheets("sheet1").Select
Range("A1:N1000") = Range("A1:N1000").Value
Sheets("sheet2").Select
Range("A1:BW1000") = Range("A1:BW1000").Value


Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End With

ChDir path

With wb
If Len(Dir(path, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
MkDir path
.SaveAs path & filename & ".xlsb", FileFormat:=50
Else
.SaveAs path & filename & ".xlsb", FileFormat:=50
End If
.Save
.Close
End With
    With sh1
        .Cells.Locked = False
        .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas).Locked = True
        .Protect Password:="password"
    End With
    With sh2
        .Cells.Locked = False
        .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas).Locked = True
        .Protect Password:="password"
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: where's the ".....code" :)

Comment: Here it is :) Nathan_Sav

Comment: Range("A1:N1000") = Range("A1:N1000").Value - that's a very interesting way of making formulas go away. Does it work? In other news, there's a difference between `Select` and `Activate` that could be relevant.

Comment: It works fine for me) At least before the worksheet was protected it was working perfectly. no doubts... Would you propose to change .Activate on .Select?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This procedure uses arrays to hold the source worksheets, names & passwords. It focuses on unprotecting the worksheets, adding the new workbook and copying the target worksheets (values and formatting), just add the other parts (i.e. protecting, saving, etc) which seems to be ok in your code.

```
'Have these declaration at begining of the module
Option Explicit
Option Base 1

Sub Wsh_CopyTo_NewWbk()
Dim aWsh As Variant
aWsh = [{"Sheet1","Wsh1";"Sheet2","Wsh2"}]
Dim aWshSrc(2) As Worksheet
Dim wbk As Workbook, wsh As Worksheet
Dim vItm As Variant, b As Byte

    Rem Set Worksheet Array
    With ThisWorkbook
        For b = 1 To UBound(aWsh)
            .Worksheets(aWsh(b, 1)).Unprotect Password:=aWsh(b, 2)
            Set aWshSrc(b) = .Worksheets(aWsh(b, 1))
    Next: End With

    Rem Add New Workbook
    Set wbk = Workbooks.Add
    With wbk
        Rem Delete All Worksheets but One
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        For Each wsh In .Worksheets
            With wsh
                If .Index = 1 Then .Name = "!DELETE" Else .Delete
        End With: Next
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True

        Rem Copy Worksheets
        For Each vItm In aWshSrc
            vItm.Copy After:=Sheets(.Sheets.Count)
            Set wsh = .Sheets(.Sheets.Count)
            wsh.UsedRange.Value = wsh.UsedRange.Value2
        Next

        Rem Delete Reamining Worksheet
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        .Worksheets("!DELETE").Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Copy` without args, which will copy the sheet to the clipboard, and then [`Pastespecial`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835858.aspx)

Something like this

```
ThisWorkbook.Activate
Sheets("sheet1").Copy
wb.Sheets(1).PasteSpecial
```

`PasteSpecial` takes an arg `Link` which is false by default. So no need to specify it. if it is false, it should not keep any references to the original sheet

Comment: Due to some reasons the first sheet is copied OK. But when the next Copied Excel creates a new workbook again... have no Idea why

Comment: PasteSpecial method of Worksheet class failed